# Perl on debian: confliciting perl installations on a system

Tags: perl, debian, cpan, apt

I updated all of the perl modules on a Debian development system (as a test) to their latest versions. I wanted to see if it was safe to upgrade the modules on the live servers.  It appeared to work, except that I started getting an odd error from Imager (relating to API version numbers, however that's not really important right now).

I tried reinstalling Imager and any related libs however nothing appeared to fix the problem.

Looking further, I've found that the development system in question appears to have multiple perl directories including;

```
/usr/lib/perl (which contains 5.14.2 and subdirs)
/usr/lib/perl5 (which contains a range of perl modules)
/usr/local/lib/perl (which contains another 5.14.2 and a set of modules)
and even /root/perl5 (which contains a small list of modules including i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int)
```

it appears (although I'm not entirely sure I'm reading this correctly), that modules on the system have been installed using every method possible, apt-get, aptitude, cpan, installed from source, and cpanminus and that different modules are ending up in different perl directories (I guess installations), mainly /usr/local/lib/perl or /usr/lib/perl5. I don't know how at least 2 different perl installations got on there.

I *think* that /usr/lib/perl is the one I want to keep,
so, I tried renaming /usr/local/lib/perl to perl.save then
linked /usr/local/lib/perl /usr/lib/perl.
Then I reinstalled any missing packages.
Most packages seem to install however for a number I'm getting this ominous message;

---

Have /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2

Want /usr/lib/perl/5.14

Your perl and your Config.pm seem to have different ideas about the
architecture they are running on.

Perl thinks: [5.14.2]

Config says: [i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int]

This may or may not cause problems. Please check your installation of perl
if you have problems building this extension.

---

After which the install of that particular module fails. Probably for good reasons.

The reason why I want to fix this is that our dev systems are all virtual, and all the other dev systems are clones of this (broken) one - so it's a problem that I need to solve hopefully without rebuilding the entire system from scratch (although his is an option).

I did try cloning the system and then purging perl, however that left me with an extremely broken system that couldn't do anything.

Any ideas for a useful approach to fixing this?
Thanks

Comment: That problem sounds like the problem someone just reported to perl5 porters, and it started with a `gcc` upgrade. His [solution](http://markmail.org/thread/hcrjgw6dmywtcp3o) was to manually fix `Config.pm`.

Comment: i've found that root's .bashrc has a number of perl environment variables added by cpanm which created /root/perl, then doing a upgrade of the systems cpan modules using cpanm put all these modules in /root/perl5.  i suspect this is the main problem, perl doesn't appear to have too many problems with files being installed across /usr/lib/perl and /usr/local/lib/perl - anyone have some insight on that?

Comment: ikegami - it could well be a similar problem, I'll also try what he suggests in his post and report back.

Comment: ok, so i've found a few things, cpanm was installed as root and configured itself to put modules in /root/perl5.  this made me realise that i've been caught by a schoolboy error - the env that root has when I sudo -s to root is different form the env if I either log in as root or su - root. And so things have been installing in a variety of palaces some of which were hidden to the other env (not included in @INC for example).  Also the system isn't finding all the of the libs because of the problem that ikegami pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per my comment above, cpanm was installed as root and configured itself to put modules in /root/perl5. this made me realise that i've been caught by a schoolboy error - the env that root has when I sudo -s to root is different from the env if I either log in as root or su - root. And so things have been installing in a variety of palaces some of which were hidden to the other env (not included in @INC for example). Also the system isn't finding all the of the libs because of the problem that ikegami pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of "perl virtualenv" projects that make use of the "local::lib" module. This lets you install stuff for your particular application in a local directory. When used correctly these will override whatever is in the system.

This one, https://github.com/stoned/pll, uses cpanm so that you can install into your virtual environment.

This might not be what you want, but is something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

just in case anyone is still have a problem with this I was doing a local 
5.18 install, (first time for me), I added the 2 libs to PERL5LIB.
I was having a problem installing Moose after the change it installed
with no issues.